# How do I add a condition to my Grafana link?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

In my Grafana dashboard (with Prometheus as a data source), I have a custom $site variable, which allows the user to pick the site from a dropdown. It's defined as:

```
Values separated by comma: prod, preprod
```

With "Include All option" checked.

And then I have a link to my Kibana Dashboard in which I use this variable to pass the selected site as follow :

```
AND site:%20$site%20
```

When either prod or preprod are selected everything works great, here's what I get :

```
AND site: prod
```

Or

```
AND site: preprod
```

but when "all" is selected I endup with this :

```
AND site: {prod,preprod}
```

I want to add an if/else to the link template so that when "all" is selected what I get is :

```
AND (site: prod OR site: preprod)
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the formatting of the variable interpolation using the advanced variable format options, described in the Grafana documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/variable-syntax/#advanced-variable-format-options/).

The option you're looking for is the "lucene" one.

Comment: Using the following format `${site:lucene}` resulted in `AND site: ("prod" OR "preprod")`  which worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I didn't pay attention to this option. I just fixed the answer pointing to the correct solution. Thanks for the info.